# Access BeanNameGenerator

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

i want to register a spring bean programatically via
`((GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext).registerBeanDefinition(name, beanDefinition);`.

However, to have a consistent bean name I want to access the BeanNameGenerator to generate the name with it.

But how do I get this?

Answer (score 0):

Classes implementing the interface `BeanNameGenerator` are not available to get from the Spring context as they are used during the context initialization. Instead, each of the classes is exposed as a singleton ([actual Java singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/java/example), not [a Spring bean with singleton scope](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-singleton)) in a public (and static) field `INSTANCE`:

```
DefaultBeanNameGenerator.INSTANCE
AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.INSTANCE
FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.INSTANCE
```

See the [BeanNameGenerator docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanNameGenerator.html) - there you can find the implementing classes and their docs as well. The `INSTANCE` fields in each class are described with more details there.